# Exclude some directories in phpdox

Tags: php, phpdoc, phpdocx

I have phpdox to generate my API documentation and it works, but i want it to exclude some directories (like Zend and smarty).
In my phpdox.xml the collector part looks like this (and it does not work):

```
    <collector publiconly="false" backend="parser">
        <!--  @publiconly - Flag to disable/enable processing of non public methods and members -->
        <!--  @backend    - The collector back end to use, currently only shipping with 'parser' -->

        <!--  <include / exclude filter for filelist generator, mask must follow fnmatch() requirements  -->
        <include mask="*.php" />
        <exclude mask="Zend/*" />
        <exclude mask="smarty/*" />

        <!--  How to handle inheritance -->
        <inheritance resolve="true">
            <!--  @resolve - Flag to enable/disable resolving of inheritance -->

            <!--  You can define multiple (external) dependencies to be included -->
            <!--  <dependency  path="" -->
            <!--    @path  - path to a directory containing an index.xml for a dependency project -->
        </inheritance>

    </collector>
```

What is wrong with the exclude masks?

Answer (score 4):

found it myself:

```
    <collector publiconly="false" backend="parser">
        <!--  @publiconly - Flag to disable/enable processing of non public methods and members -->
        <!--  @backend    - The collector backend to use, currently only shipping with 'parser' -->

        <!--  <include / exclude filter for filelist generator, mask must follow fnmatch() requirements  -->
        <include mask="*.php" />
        <exclude mask="**Zend**"/>
        <exclude mask="**smarty**"/>

        <!--  How to handle inheritance -->
        <inheritance resolve="true">
            <!--  @resolve - Flag to enable/disable resolving of inheritance -->

            <!--  You can define multiple (external) dependencies to be included -->
            <!--  <dependency  path="" -->
            <!--    @path  - path to a directory containing an index.xml for a dependency project -->
        </inheritance>

    </collector>
```

One must use a  "**DIRNAME**" approach to do so, see code above.

Comment: Does not work for me because everything down the tree containing the "excluded tag" gets excluded.